# Compare comma delimited strings in SQL

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, varchar

I have search requests that come in a CDL `("1,2,3,4")`,`("1,5")`. I need to compare that to another CDL and return back all records that have a match. The kicker is the position of each number isn't always the same.

I've got something almost working except for instances where I'm trying to match `("2,5")` to `("2,4,5")`. Obviously the strings aren't equal but I need to return that match, because it has all the values in the first CDL.

[My SQL Fiddle should make it fairly clear...](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2cf8b/5/0)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Oh and I saw this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215902/search-a-varchar-field-that-contains-all-words-from-another-string) is similar, but that seems a little drastic and over my head but I'll see if I can try to understand it.

**Edit**
So I just did a replace to change `("2,5")` to `("%2%5%")` and changed the were to use `LIKE`. From what I can initially tell it seems to be working.. [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/909f2/1/0) Any reason I shouldn't do this or maybe I'm crazy and it doesn't work at all?

Comment: perhaps it would be easier if you could generate uniform CDL instead (can't see the fiddle, so maybe my comment is completely irrelevant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just one step further, get closer to your answer. 
**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2cf8b/9)**

```
SELECT P.* 
FROM Product P
CROSS APPLY(
  SELECT *
  FROM ShelfSearch SS
  WHERE Patindex(char(37)+replace(ss.shelflist, ',',char(37))+char(37),p.shelflist) > 0
)Shelfs
```

Comment: Nice, that's basically what I did in my "Edit". Now I just hope performance isn't ridiculously bad. The CSV's shouldn't get more than maybe 20 so I'll have to test and see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the lists to a table with the following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION DelimitedStringToTable (@cdl varchar(8000), @delimiter varchar(1))
RETURNS @list table (
    Token varchar(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @token varchar(1000)
DECLARE @position int

SET @cdl = @cdl + @delimiter -- tack on delimiter to end 
SET @position = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @cdl, 1)
    WHILE @position > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @token = LEFT(@cdl, @position - 1)
            INSERT INTO @list (Token) VALUES (@token)
            SET @cdl = RIGHT(@cdl, DATALENGTH(@cdl) - @position)        
            SET @position = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @cdl, 1)      
        END 
    RETURN
END
```

Then you can use something like this to find all the matches:

```
SELECT list1.* 
FROM DelimitedStringToTable('1,2,3', ',') list1
INNER JOIN DelimitedStringToTable('2', ',') list2 ON list1.Token = list2.Token
```